# Product of Lebesgue measure of the cross is the multiplication of the measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ two bounded and Lebesgue measurable sets. I have to show that $A\times B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable.

My first problem is to give a characterizion of $A\times B$ only knowing that $A,B$ are bounded.

I found some similitarity with this question [Lebesgue Measure of the Cartesian Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/lebesgue-measure-of-the-cartesian-product)

Comment: What is your definition of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @EricWofsey The measure of $A  \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by: $ \lambda(A):=inf \{ {\sum}_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(Q_i):  Q_i\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ closed rectangle, $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}Q_i\}$

Comment: Sorry can no longer edit the previous comment,  $ \mu(Q)$ is the Jordan measure, defined by: $ \mu(Q):= \int_Q {1_Q}  \ d\mu $